# What do the symbols mean in the second line

Tags: pdf, encoding

The teacher posed the following problem: there is some pdf; open it in wordpad (as a variant), look at the encoding:

```
 % PDF-1.3 
 %·ѕ­Є
```

Question: What do the symbols mean in the second line and is there some vulnerability in these codes?

Answer (score 2):

These four characters have no specific meaning. They were introduced in order to attempt to make sure that the file is treated as binary, and not as text.